# how to convert webpage apostrophe (&#8217;) to ascii 39 in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby

That's pretty much it.  I'm using Nokogiri to scrape a web page what has &#8217 ; characters in it, and I can't figure out how to do the conversion.  here's what I tried:

```
str.gsub(/&#8217;/,"'")  
str.gsub("&#8217;","'")  
str.gsub("ΓÇÖ","'") # that's how it looks when I do a puts
```

(In the above, there's no space between the &#8217 and the ";", but if I don't put the space in, SO converts it to an apostrophe -- the cruel, cruel irony!)

I'm sure this is covered somewhere, but couldn't find the solution here or on the web.

TIA

Comment: I took the check (= answered") off because while this solution worked great for 1.8.7, when using 1.9.1, I get `gsub': incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError).  I thought the admins here would prefer I "reopen" this question rather than post an almost-identical one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.gsub("\342\200\231", "'")` should work

I got this from:

```rb
    '’'.to_s
=> "\342\200\231"
```

Other html characters that may be substituted ( http://ask.metafilter.com/62656/Eliminating-odd-characters-from-web-site ):

```
"\342\200\176" - "'"  
"\342\200\177" - "'"  
"\342\200\230" - "'"  
"\342\200\231" - "'"  
"\342\200\232" - ','  
"\342\200\233" - "'"  
"\342\200\234" - '"'  
"\342\200\235" - '"'  
"\342\200\041" - '-'  
"\342\200\174" - '-'  
"\342\200\220" - '-'  
"\342\200\223" - '-'  
"\342\200\224" - '--'  
"\342\200\225" - '--'  
"\342\200\042" - '--'  
"\342\200\246" - '...'
```

Comment: that worked great for 1.8.7, thanks.  For 1.9.1, I found out, that gives the error I mentioned in the comment at my original post.  For 1.9.1, I had to use   
str.gsub("&#8217;","'")  
sheesh!